# C++ hierarchical class inheritance design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

Suppose that I have the following application logic:

```
class classA
{
    classA(ConfigA config)
};

class classB
{
     classB(ConfigB config)
};

class App
{
    void initial(Config config){
        if( cond1)
            new classA(config.getConfigA());
        if( cond2)
            new classB(config.getConfigB());
     }
};
```

Is there good pattern to design the Config structure? Currently what I am doing is

```
struct BConfig
{
     int a;
     int b;
};

struct ConfigA:public BConfig
{
     int c;
};
struct ConfigB:public BConfig
{
     int d;
};
struct Config
{
    ConfigA getConfigA();
    ConfigB getConfigB();
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};
```

I guess there is better way to do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: What are `cond1` and `cond2`? What do you want to do with classes `classA` and `classB` once created? Let them leak doesn't sound like a good choice...

Comment: It's imcomplete code. I mean there is some config branch. The branch can continue inside ConfigA.

Comment: Provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: @skypjack  Sorry about that, but it's already a mvce. It's about how to design the top config structure.

Comment: Is this some mutated kind of the factory pattern?

Comment: The problem with your question is that this is no 'application logic'. Is just some class hierarchy with unclear purpose. You have better chances to receive meaningful help if you explain the context and the goal of your design.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an XY problem. You have a particular solution you're trying to get working that may or may not be the answer to your original problem. Also your usage of `new` is incomplete in the example, it is unclear when or how `Class` objects are freed.

That said, consider using interface patterns - something like this (still needs work but it's a start):

```
struct IConfig {
  // TODO: identification as to which class instance this is.
  // and/or virtual methods
  int a;
  int b;
  virtual ~IConfig(){}
};

struct ConfigA : public IConfig {
  int c;
  virtual ~ConfigA(){}
};

struct ConfigB : public IConfig {
  int d;
  virtual ~ConfigB(){}
};

class IClass {
  // TODO: identification as to which class instance this is.
  // and/or virtual methods
  virtual ~IClass(){}
};

class ClassA : public IClass {
  public:
    ClassA(const IConfig & iconf) {
      ConfigA & aconf = dynamic_cast<ConfigA&>(iconf);
    }
  virtual ~ClassA(){}
};

class ClassB : public IClass {
  public:
    ClassB(const IConfig & iconf) {
      ConfigB & bconf = dynamic_cast<ConfigB&>(iconf);
    }
  virtual ~ClassB(){}
};

class App {
    IConfig * config; // in case
    IClass * cls;
    void initial(IConfig config){
      if( cond1 )
        cls = new ClassA( config );
      else if( cond2 )
        cls = new ClassB( config );
      else
        // ...
    }
};
```

Just be sure with such a solution that `cond1` will be true IIF the `IConfig` being passed to `initial` is of type `ConfigA` to match the class being created. You can add more checks to ensure that's the case into the interface itself. A virtual method that returns a constant should be good enough but it really depends what you're trying to achieve in doing this, as it seems like a messy approach already.

Eg, perhaps a config local to `IConfig` could be used to determine both - which class to load, which in turn determines which Config class should be used, etc.

Afterthought - you may in this case want to let each `Class` have its own implementation of `IConfig`, which lets `App` (using `IConfig` data) determine which class to create. Again, without knowing what you're trying to achieve with this structure (as opposed to some other) no one can say for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is the best I can get now. Since my App may contains dynamic  derived classes, and different classes have different configurations. The whole App configuration is specified in a single file.  I was trying to find a design pattern about configuration interface which is suitable for this case.